# Check UIButton already exists or not in Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I found Objective-C coding for this topic. But the problem is that most of the classes and functions in Objective-C is deprecated in swift programming language.

I am using a UIButton inside a UITableView with `flagForAction[Boolean Value]`. So what i want to achieve is that if the UIButton is created once ,  there is no need to recreate it. So for that i need to check whether the UIButton already exists or not. Somebody suggested me the concept of tag for this, applying a particular tag to this UIButton and checking that is exist on the view or not. But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Objective-C is deprecated? I didn't got *that* message.

Comment: @dasdom Create a UIButton like this, var MyButton:UIButton = UIButton(),   MyButton.class , in Swift the .class cross marked.

Comment: You're holding it wrong. In Swift you can check the class with `myButton is UIButton`. By the way: instances should not start with a lower case letter. I recommend you read the Swift book before you write an App in Swift.

Comment: @dasdom Yeah okay. So what about the answer to this question.?

Comment: Is the button within a table view cell?

Comment: @dasdom Yes. But have to create it dynamically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using view as example. You can also identify a button with accessibilityIdentifier property of the button, if you dont want to use tag proprerty of button. 
For example :

```
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44))
    button.accessibilityIdentifier = "button 1"
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Here, i created a button with accessibilityIdentifier "button 1"

While creating the next button, i will check in the subview if it contains the button with accessibilityIdentifier "button 1", as below

```
    var subviews : NSArray = self.view.subviews
    for button : AnyObject in subviews{

        if(button .isKindOfClass(UIButton)){

            if(button.accessibilityIdentifier == "button 1"){

                println("Button Already Exists")
            }else{
                println("Create new button")

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Strange hack. The accessibilityIdentifier should be used for something else.

Comment: Horribly inefficient iterating through all subviews. Horrible hack that will behave poorly for users who use accessibility features. Read the docs and use a tag, or subclass UITableView as per @dasdom's answer

Answer (score 3):

Setting a tag:

```
myButton.tag = 1234 // some unique value, probably better to define as an enum or constant
```

Retrieving a view by tag (likely in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
if let myButton = tableviewCell.viewWithTag(1234) { // change tableviewCell for whatever your tableview cell variable name is
    // myButton already existed
} else {
    // TableviewCell doesn't contain a myButton, so create one here and set the tag as above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in **swift 2.0**

```
for view in myview.subviews {

      if let btn : UIButton = view as? UIButton {
           // access button here, either tag or title etc..
      }

 }
```